# Express each of the vectors in terms of i, j, and k when k is not parallel to any of the sides (and the figure is tilted)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

In the following question, I am absolutely unsure of how to find vectors $AM$ and $GM$.
[image]
I know that, to find a vector, $AM$ would equal $OM - OA$.

(I think) my issue is that the direction $k$ is not parallel to the vertical sides of the solid. Also, I have not been given any sides lengths.

My textbook does not shine any light into this, and I do not have anyone else to ask for help.

Here's what I've come up with:
$$OM = (xi, 4j, 5k)$$
I got 8 for x, but it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\vec{OA} = 8i$, $\vec{OD} = 3i+10k$

As $|AB| = |OC| = |OA|$ and $AB \parallel OC, \vec{AB} = 8j$

As $|AE| = |OD|$ and $AE \parallel OD, \vec{AE} = 3i+10k$

$\vec{AF} = \vec{AB} + \vec{AE} = 3i + 8j + 10k$

So, $\vec{AM} = \frac{3}{2}i + 4j + 5k \,$ (as its magnitude is half of $\vec{AF}$).

Now, $\vec{FM} = -\vec{AM} = -\frac{3}{2}i - 4j - 5k \, , \vec{GF} = 8i$.

So, $\vec{GM} = \vec{GF} + \vec{FM} = \frac{13}{2}i - 4j-5k$.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

Note that $OABC$ is a square.

Hence $OC= 8j$, $OB = OA+AB=8(i+j)$ and

$OF=OB+BF=OB+OD=8(i+j)+(3i+10k)$

Now that you know $OF$, you can compute $AF$ and hence $AM$.
I will leave the rest to you.